# Does Clang guess branch probabilities? How exactly?

Tags: c, clang

Does Clang guess branch probabilities? If yes, then how exactly?

Example: this code:

```
void foo(void);
void bar(void);
int f(int x)
{
    if (x == 1) {
        foo();
    }
    bar();
    bar();
    bar();
    return x;
}
```

compiled with `gcc -O3` leads to this code:

```
f(int):
        push    rbx
        mov     ebx, edi
        cmp     edi, 1
        je      .L5
.L2:
        call    bar()
        call    bar()
        call    bar()
        mov     eax, ebx
        pop     rbx
        ret
.L5:
        call    foo()
        jmp     .L2
```

while compiled with `clang -O3` leads to this code:

```
f(int):                                  # @f(int)
        push    rbx
        mov     ebx, edi
        cmp     edi, 1
        jne     .LBB0_2
        call    foo()@PLT
.LBB0_2:                                # %if.end
        call    bar()@PLT
        call    bar()@PLT
        call    bar()@PLT
        mov     eax, ebx
        pop     rbx
        ret
```

Here we see that:

- GCC considers that probability of `x == 1` being true is low (ICC computes it as 5%: `Prob 5%`). Hence, the `je .L5` is likely not taken.
- Clang considers that probability of `x == 1` being true is high. Hence, the `jne .LBB0_2` is likely not taken.

Question: why Clang considers that probability of `x == 1` being true is high? Does Clang guess branch probabilities? If yes, then how exactly?

Notes:

- GCC guesses branch probabilities using heuristics. There is `-fno-guess-branch-probability` option.
- ICC guesses branch probabilities too. For example, `x == 1` is true is 5%, `x >= 1` is true is 78%, `x >= 0` is true is 40%. I don't know how exactly these numbers are computed. You can try other conditions: https://godbolt.org/z/K4zs41q5P.